# How to convert pandas df to dictionary with lists nested in the list?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I recently started working with python and I am now working with API request. I need to convert dataframe to a dictionary of lists nested in the list.

**How to convert** `df`:

```
data = {'x':  ['15.0', '42.2','43.4','89.0','45.8'],
        'y': ['10.1', '42.3','43.5','5.0','45.9']
         }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['x','y'])
```

**To dictionary of lists nested in the list**

```
{
  "Points": [
    [15.0, 10.1],    [42.2, 42.3],    [43.4, 43.5],    [89.0, 5.0],    [45.8, 45.9]
  ]
}
```

I tried using `df.to_dict` with list as a orient parameter but the result is 2 long lists of x and y instead of many pair-lists.

Probably trivial problem for python users, thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Convert values to numpy array by [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) and then to list:

```
d = {"Points":df.to_numpy().tolist()}
#if there is more columns
#d = {"Points":df[['x','y']].to_numpy().tolist()}
print (d)
{'Points': [['15.0', '10.1'], ['42.2', '42.3'], 
            ['43.4', '43.5'], ['89.0', '5.0'], ['45.8', '45.9']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:-

```
res = {'Points' : [[row['x'], row['y']] for i, row in df.iterrows()]}
print(res)
```

Output:-

```
{'Points': [['15.0', '10.1'], ['42.2', '42.3'], ['43.4', '43.5'], ['89.0', '5.0'], ['45.8', '45.9']]}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
output = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    output['Points'] = [[row['x'], row['y']]

print(output)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316

Comment: I did not know that before. Thank you. :)